# How do I extract only words with underscores?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, nested-lists, gensim

I have a Gensim bigram output that I need to append to a list.
The actual output is

```
output = ['stai', 'fantast', 'intern', 'hotel', 'la', 'vega', 'hotel', 'collect', 'la', 'vega', 'la', 'vega', 'asp', 
 ['stai',  'fantast',  'intern_hotel',  'la_vega',  'hotel',  'collect',  'la_vega',  'la_vega',  'asp']]
```

I am trying to pull out the bigrams from the last element so my output looks like

```
##output should look like output = ['stai', 'fantast', 'intern', 'hotel', 'la',
##'vega', 'hotel', 'collect', 'la', 'vega', 'la', 'vega', 'asp', intern_hotel',
##'la_vega',  'la_vega',  'la_vega']
```

The underscore seems to be giving me a hard time

```
    substring = "_"

    for item in output:
        if substring not in item:
            output.remove(item)
    output
##returns ['fantast', 'intern_hotel', 'la_vega', 'collect', 'la_vega', 'la_vega'] instead of
```

What I am trying to do is just return the bigrams with underscores.  Why is fantast and collect still in the list?

Comment: Don't delete items from the list while iterating over it. Instead, filter it such as `[e for e in output if substring in e]`